# regarding setup project interpreter in Pycharm and make it point to a virtual environment created within Anaconda

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, virtualenv

I have created a virtual environment, i.e., `TF`, under Anaconda. Within this virtual environment, `TF`,  I have installed all the packages that I need for my project. At present, I also install `Pycharm`. For a given project, e.g., `testPycharmAnaconda`, how can I develop it using `Pycharm`, while ensure the interpreter for this project using the virtual environment `TF` installed in Anaconda.

I go to the setting page of `Pycharm`, for the three options on the right panel, which one should I choose, and how to finish the according setup? Thanks.

[check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQQw5.jpg)

Then as suggested, I choose the conda environment, the following figure shows how I make selection

[image]

But after making the selection, I got the following error message,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in selecting the environment "Conda Environment" in the middle :)

this will let you use your newly created anaconda environment

I found a few resources that might help you in the future: (the UI is different in several of these but do not worry)

https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/setting-up-pycharm-with-anaconda-plus-installing-packages-windows-mac-db2b158bd8c

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html.html#conda

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks, I did as you suggested, but I got the error message, which is now included in the updated post. Thanks.

Comment: in the picture where the box says "Select Path to conda Executable" you selected python - but in the Anaconda folder there should be a `conda.exe` somewhere

Comment: it's probably in `Anaconda/bin`